# When using Tabulator in angular why do I not have access to outside variables in the rowClick funtion?

Tags: angular, tabulator

I have the following tabulator in an angular component.

```
new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      data: this.tableData,
      columns: this.columnNames,
      layout: 'fitDataStretch',
      rowClick(e, row) {
        console.log('Row: ' + row.getData().format + ' ' + this.name);
      }
    });
```

however `this.name` is undefined even though it is defined in the component.

```
export class example implements OnInit {

  private partner: string;
  private name: string;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public texto:string = 'hola mundo';`

```
private drawTable(): void {
  new Tabulator(this.tab, {
     data: this.tableData,
     columns: this.columnNames,
     rowClick:(e, row)=>{
       //e - the click event object
       //row - row component
       alert(this.texto);
     },
  });
```

}